# How to chain two custom_targets in meson?

Tags: meson-build

Two properly build my target, I need to chain two custom commands in meson:

- gob2 - That translates a .gob file to a pair of .c and .h files
- patch_src - A small python program that makes a small patch of the gob2 output.

But I can't figure out how to give the  patch_src command the output of the gob2 program as input. If I do the following:

```
gob2 = find_program('gob2')
patch_src = find_program('patch_src')

gen_src = custom_target('gen-output',
  output : ['gtk-image-viewer.h','gtk-image-viewer-private.h','gtk-image-viewer.c'],
  input : 'gtk-image-viewer.gob',
  command : [gob2, '-o', '@OUTDIR@', '@INPUT@'],
  )

fixed_src = custom_target('patch-output',
  output : ['gtk-image-viewer-fixed.c'],
  input : 'gtk-image-viewer.c',
  command : [patch_src, 'gtk-image-viewer.c','@OUTPUT@'],
  )
```

I obviously get the error that `gtk-image-viewer.c` is not found, which makes sense as it is written to `@OUTPUTDIR@`. But how do I specify to meson to look for `gtk-image-viewer.c` in `@OUTPUTDIR@`?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `gen_src[3]` for example as the `input` directly and meson will set up the dependencies and use the correct path to it.

```
fixed_src = custom_target('patch-output',
  output : ['gtk-image-viewer-fixed.c'],
  input  : gen_src[3],
  command : [patch_src, '@INPUT@','@OUTPUT@'],
)
```